# How to validate a json field using Yup?

Tags: yup

I have this:

```js
const jsonField = { [key]: value };
```

How can I validate that with Yup?
Keeping in mind that the shape of the object changes a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It appears that Yup has a mixed validator to use in this case.

```js
Yup.mixed()
```

Comment: ._.
Sry, but your answer is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

**I found this with yup validation**  use this    `apiResponse: JSON.parse(value.apiResponse)` while post data by axios

```js
 apiResponse: Yup.string().test("json", "Invalid JSON format", (value) => {
      try {
        JSON.parse(value);
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
    }),
```